# What does it mean to subtract $\phi$ in the context of linear systems?

Tags: notation

I'm trying to implement the algorithm described in [Natarajan (1995, p .3)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f629/5fd69d76d606f66cc15f58767a8161d60335.pdf) but I have a regrettably poor grasp of how to read the notation involved.  I've managed to tease out most of it (I think) but I'm stumped on this bit:

> choose $k \in \{1,2,...,n\} - \tau$ such that $a_k^{(r)}$ of $\mathbf{A}^{(r)}$ is closest to $b^{(r)}$

Before that point, it establishes the initial state $\tau \leftarrow \phi$, and I've gathered that capital Phi is either the reciprocal of the golden ratio or the CDF of the standard normal distribution.  Looking forward, I see $\tau \leftarrow \tau \cup \{k\}$, which I believe would indicate the latter.

Unfortunately, neither case really makes sense to me because my intuition says $k \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ is going to be a scalar integer; a column index of A (because we're really choosing a column $a_k^{(r)}$ to project).

I'm clearly missing something, so I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: $\phi$ is the empty set.

Comment: @themaker So this is just a simple mistake where he put $\phi$ instead of $\varnothing$?  That... makes a lot of sense, actually. orz